# How to get the dynamic image inside 'startAdornment' in MUI's Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, typescript, material-ui

I am using MUI's autocomplete component to display some of my objects as suggestions.
Everything is working fine, but I am placing an avatar as a start adornment inside of the textfield (inside of renderInput), where I wish to put the value of corresponding image prop of what is selected.

**What I want** : I want that whatever value is selected in autocomplete, (there is an image property inside my object, whose array i mapped to **options** *prop* of *autocomplete*). So, I want that corresponding image,  together with the option label (inside of textfield), the corresponding image should also be shown inside  **startAdornment**.
Well, *I want it similar to LinkedIn's **company field** which we fills while posting a new job.*

Here's my MUI Autocomplete, I am new to 'typescript'.

```
 <Autocomplete
         open = {open}
         onOpen = {() => setOpen(true)}
         onClose = {() => setClose(true)}
         options = {items.sort((a, b) => -b.name.localeCompare(a.name))}
         isOptionEqualToValue = {(option, value) => option.name === value.name}
         getOptionLabel = {(option : any) => option.name}
         renderInput = {(params : any ) => (
           <TextField
            {...params}
            className = {'inputField'} 
            placeholder = {'Enter item name'}
            label = {'items'}
            InputProps = {{
              ...params.InputProps,
              startAdornment : ( <Avatar src = {params.image} /> ) 
             }} />
         )}
         renderOption = {(props, option) => {

          return (
            <li
             key = {option.id}
             {option.name}
            </li> )}} />
```

so I want that whatever name is selected from autocomplete, its corrosponding image should be displayed into the Avatar(inside of startadornment).
How to achieve this?

And, yes, here is my Object array be like -

```
[{ id : number, name : string, image : string }, {...}, {...}, and so on...];
```

*image here is url of the image, ( that I wish to show into the avatar inside startAdornment.)*

*Do i need to provide a new state for this?*

All suggestions would be appretiated, eagerly looking for answers that fits.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to create a state to store the select value and whenever this state changes it would update the avatar component:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState("");

const AvatarAdornment = useMemo(()=> 
    <Avatar src={items.find(item =>item.name === value).image} />,
[value, items])
```

And in your autocomplete component use it like:

```
<Autocomplete
     open = {open}
     onOpen = {() => setOpen(true)}
     onClose = {() => setClose(true)}
     options = {items.sort((a, b) => -b.name.localeCompare(a.name))}
     isOptionEqualToValue = {(option, value) => option.name === value.name}
     getOptionLabel = {(option : any) => option.name}
     renderInput = {(params : any ) => (
       <TextField
        {...params}
        className = {'inputField'} 
        placeholder = {'Enter item name'}
        label = {'items'}
        InputProps = {{
          ...params.InputProps,
          startAdornment : ( <AvatarAdornment/> ) 
         }} />
     )}
     renderOption = {(props, option) => {

      return (
        <li
         key = {option.id}
         {option.name}
        </li> )}} />
```

Comment: Where are you updating the `value` with the Autocomplete value?

Comment: Use the onChange event of Autocomplete do update the state: `onChange={(e)=>setValue(e.target.value)}`